# Total size of package files downloaded via `yum update`

Tags: rhel, yum

Is there a command that shows how much space will the downloaded package files take when `yum update` is run?

To clarify, I'm asking about the size of the downloaded files placed in `/var` prior to installing, not the size of the installed packages.

The aim of the question is to check whether there is enough free space on the `/var` partition before launching  `yum update`.

Comment: I think yum itself shows how much data will be downloaded, before you hit y and enter. Isn't it ?

Comment: @Sagar Yes, but I'd like a less kludgy way than parsing the output of `yum update`.

Comment: Yum needs to know what all packages should be updated and I dont see any other way than parsing yum output to know exact size. Raman posted answer looks nice me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "N" | yum update | awk -F: '/^Total download size/ { print $2 }'
```

This will get you the size of the downloaded files.

```
df -h /var | awk 'NR==2 { print $4 }'
```

This will get you the space available in /var

Only challenge then is processing the possibility of different size denominations.

Comment: Thanks.  I already thought of this solution but I was hoping there was some other way (some obscure `yum` command, etc.)